# Is a List<BlockingCollection<T>> Thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I wan't to maintain a list of several [BlockingCollections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
List<BlockingCollection<ExtDocument>> a = new List<BlockingCollection<ExtDocument>>();
```

And the check in subthreads if any of the 'queues' still have items pending:

```
if (a.Where(x => x.IsAddingCompleted).Count > 0)
```

Is the usage of a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) in this case thread-safe **if the number of items in the list don't change after the initialisation** (the content of the blockinglists inside the collection will change offcourse...)?

Or should i opt for an `array of BlockingCollection` or the following construction:

```
BlockingCollection<BlockingCollection<workitem>> a = new BlockingCollection<BlockingCollection<workitem>>();
```

Comment: If the list doesn't change after initialization, it's perfectly fine to just use a list. Only reading is not the problem with concurrency, it's its mutability that makes it a problem eventually.

Comment: I'd rather use an array instead of `List<T>`. That way it's clearer that the number of items won't change.

Comment: @Caramiriel Thank you for the information! CodesInChaos: Thanks for the tip. This will indeed increase the readibilty for future programmers

Comment: Or `IReadOnlyList<T>` when you have the ability to use .NET-framework 4.5 (which `T[]` inherits by-the-way).

Comment: This might be an overkill, but you can also look into [Immutable Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn385366(v=vs.110).aspx). An [`ImmutableList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185(v=vs.111).aspx) or [`ImmutableArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray(v=vs.111).aspx) perhaps.

Comment: Tons of good advices! Thnx Guys! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A nice benefit from using an array instead of `List<T>` is that you can then use `BlockingCollection<T>.TakeFromAny` and similar methods. Most likely, you're approaching your problem from the wrong angle - your processing threads could then simply do `BlockingCollection<T>.TryTakeFromAny`, and if it's false, you're done. Completely thread-safe, and rather well performing. So your processing loop will look something like this:

```
while (BlockingCollection<ExtDocument>.TryTakeFromAny(collections, out workItem) >= 0)
{
  // Do work on workItem
}

// We're done!
```

Comment: Quite nice indeed. Must have read over that on the msdn-page. Will test it shortly!

Comment: Indeed a much better then the code I was having thusfar. Thnx!